# multi-root workspace is there a way to build all projects?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If one was to bring in 3 projects into a workspace, can you build all 3 at once like in visual studio?  If I have 2 class libraries and a web project and make changes in one of the class libs, will i have to run dotnet build on each?